# When baking bread in a multi cooker is some water required?

Tags: baking, bread, equipment

If I want to bake bread in a multi-cooker, do I still need a small amount of water at the base of the inner bowl?

Answer (score 1):

No - think of the inner bowl as a loaf or sheet pan the dough is in contact with, and instead of air transferring heat energy from the heating elements to the pan, the heating element is already in direct contact with the pan and outputting much less energy.

If your inner bowl is plain stainless steel, you may want to add a thin layer of cooking oil or parchment to prevent sticking.